# Using purrr and map to loop over deeper layers of a list?

Tags: r, purrr

I'm trying to see how to extract values from the nth level of a nested list. For example...if these were all on the second layer, I could just use `map()` like so:

```
> testlist1 <- 
+   list(
+     list('veggie' = 'apple', 'food' = 'bacon'),
+     list('veggie' = 'banana', 'food' = 'burger'),
+     list('veggie' = 'tomato', 'food' = 'sausage'),
+     list('veggie' = 'pickle', 'food' = 'chicken'),
+     list('veggie' = 'chestnut', 'food' = 'salmon'),
+     list('veggie' = 'seaweed', 'food' = 'tuna')
+   )
> 
> testlist1 %>% map('veggie')
[[1]]
[1] "apple"

[[2]]
[1] "banana"

[[3]]
[1] "tomato"

[[4]]
[1] "pickle"

[[5]]
[1] "chestnut"

[[6]]
[1] "seaweed"
```

But when they are deeper, I imagine there must be some `map()` method of looping to the layers? Example:

```
testlist2 <- list(
  list(
    list(
      list('veggie' = 'apple', 'food' = 'bacon')
    ), 
    list(
      list('veggie' = 'banana', 'food' = 'burger')
    )
  ),
  list(
    list(
      list('veggie' = 'tomato', 'food' = 'sausage')
    ), 
    list(
      list('veggie' = 'pickle', 'food' = 'chicken')
    )
  ),
  list(
    list(
      list('veggie' = 'chestnut', 'food' = 'salmon')
    ), 
    list(
      list('veggie' = 'seaweed', 'food' = 'tuna')
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like `map_depth(testlist2, 3, "veggie") %>% unlist()` in this case?

Comment: Or perhaps `testlist2 %>% map(map_chr, map_chr, "veggie")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @MrFlick suggested, `map_depth` can help here

```
library(tidyverse)

testlist2 <- list(
  list(
    list(
      list('veggie' = 'apple', 'food' = 'bacon')
    ), 
    list(
      list('veggie' = 'banana', 'food' = 'burger')
    )
  ),
  list(
    list(
      list('veggie' = 'tomato', 'food' = 'sausage')
    ), 
    list(
      list('veggie' = 'pickle', 'food' = 'chicken')
    )
  ),
  list(
    list(
      list('veggie' = 'chestnut', 'food' = 'salmon')
    ), 
    list(
      list('veggie' = 'seaweed', 'food' = 'tuna')
    )
  )
)
```

Use the first argument to set the desired list depth

```
testlist2 %>% map_depth(3, 'veggie')
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]][[1]]
#> [1] "apple"
#> 
#> 
#> [[1]][[2]]
#> [[1]][[2]][[1]]
#> [1] "banana"
#> 
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]][[1]]
#> [[2]][[1]][[1]]
#> [1] "tomato"
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]][[2]]
#> [[2]][[2]][[1]]
#> [1] "pickle"
#> 
#> 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [[3]][[1]]
#> [[3]][[1]][[1]]
#> [1] "chestnut"
#> 
#> 
#> [[3]][[2]]
#> [[3]][[2]][[1]]
#> [1] "seaweed"
```

Or use negative numbers to count up from the lowest level

```
testlist2 %>% map_depth(-2, 'veggie')
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]][[1]]
#> [1] "apple"
#> 
#> 
#> [[1]][[2]]
#> [[1]][[2]][[1]]
#> [1] "banana"
#> 
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]][[1]]
#> [[2]][[1]][[1]]
#> [1] "tomato"
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]][[2]]
#> [[2]][[2]][[1]]
#> [1] "pickle"
#> 
#> 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [[3]][[1]]
#> [[3]][[1]][[1]]
#> [1] "chestnut"
#> 
#> 
#> [[3]][[2]]
#> [[3]][[2]][[1]]
#> [1] "seaweed"

Created on 2019-11-18 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about unlisting the data and select the elements with the required name ?

```
temp <- unlist(testlist2)
unname(temp[names(temp) == "veggie"])
#[1] "apple"    "banana"   "tomato"   "pickle"   "chestnut" "seaweed"
```

This will work even when data is multiple layers deep.